# Running Grunt and Node as batch files through cron

Tags: node.js, cron, gruntjs

The last thing I'd expect to have trouble with.

I have a grunt file that needs to run every minute. It runs JSHint, captures the output, and emails it through Amazon SES. It works fine when run on the command line. However, it simply fails silently when run through cron. Nothing happens. I broke the email send out into a seperate node file. It will not run by itself. I took out all the reading of files from this second file, and tried to run it all by itself, just sending an email with the values hard coded. No dice. Again, runs fine when run from the command line.

I can see the entries in the cron log that says they are running. I have opened up the access on all affected files and directories, to anyone can execute. I have hard coded all the directory paths, to make sure it's not silently failing through not finding a file.

Here's the cron entry:
    */1 * * * *  sh /var/test/trunk/build/batch_jshint.sh

Here's the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/node/bin
cd /var/test/trunk/build/
grunt jshint_check --gruntfile /var/test/trunk/build/Grunt_jshint.js
node /var/test/trunk/build/send_jshint_email.js
```

Cron logs:
    Jul 18 22:23:01 ip-10-251-25-8 CRON[2923]: (ubuntu) CMD (sh /var/SmartGlass/sg2-nfl/trunk/build/batch_jshint.sh)
    Jul 18 22:23:01 ip-10-251-25-8 CRON[2924]: (ubuntu) CMD (sh /var/SmartGlass/sg2-nfl/trunk/build/test.sh)
    Jul 18 22:23:01 ip-10-251-25-8 CRON[2925]: (ubuntu) CMD (/usr/bin/uptime > /tmp/uptime)
    Jul 18 22:23:01 ip-10-251-25-8 CRON[2922]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
    Jul 18 22:24:01 ip-10-251-25-8 CRON[2932]: (ubuntu) CMD (sh /var/SmartGlass/sg2-nfl/trunk/build/batch_jshint.sh)
    Jul 18 22:24:01 ip-10-251-25-8 CRON[2933]: (ubuntu) CMD (sh /var/SmartGlass/sg2-nfl/trunk/build/test.sh)
    Jul 18 22:24:01 ip-10-251-25-8 CRON[2934]: (ubuntu) CMD (/usr/bin/uptime > /tmp/uptime)
    Jul 18 22:24:01 ip-10-251-25-8 CRON[2931]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

Any suggestions would be gratefully accepted, as I'm pretty much stumped right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, the one thing I didn't check. I had to include the path to the node and grunt executables in the batch file. Despite the fact that I don't have to do that when logged in, and it's the same user running the cron jobs.

Comment: Can you clarify what you exactly did? Because I'm not clear what to add to my $PATH in my bash script.

Comment: It's the path to the grunt or node executable. So, I have grunt jshint_check --gruntfile /var/test/trunk/build/Grunt_jshint.js. I can't have just 'grunt'. It would have to be something like /var/lib/bin/grunt. So, wherever that exectuble, grunt or node, exists on your server.

Comment: thank you for coming back on this! Appreciate it :) I figured it out yesterday in the late hours, indeed I had to add the `/usr/local/bin` to my path. that solved it. I think it's a weird behaviour that the crontab of a user does not include the `/usr/local/bin` path, but whatever. It works now :)