# Using gruntjs to optimize images older than X days

Tags: gruntjs

I just found Grunt this morning while looking for some ways to compress images on a Discourse forum. Is there a way to specify a date range to Grunt? I would like to be able to run a cron once a month and tell Grunt to compress any images in a folder including subfolders older than X days but also of course not to go and recompress anything that's already been compressed in the past.

Comment: Hi @MitchellK, Assuming you run a cron once a month, are you looking to optimize only the images that have been created/modified within the last month (i.e optimize only those images that were created/modified since  the cron last run a month ago)? Apologies if this is a silly question, I'm just trying to understand the logic of your requirement and what _"older than X days"_ really means?

Comment: Hi @RobC thanks for replying. Hopefully I can explain a bit better. I'd like Grunt to be able to be given a variable. let's say in this example say 90 days. So the cron should take today's date and then optimize any images in the specified folder and subfolders that are 90 days older than today. It's basically a way of compressing large images posted to the Discourse forum on topics that are aging or closed already.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) called [grunt-contrib-imagemin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-imagemin) which handles image optimization. Grunt doesn't have a specific way to set a date range like that found in *cron* tasks. You will need to utilize some custom JavaScript in your `Gruntfile.js` configuration to achieve this.

---

**Gruntfile.js**

Your custom `Gruntfile.js` can be configured as follows:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    'use strict';

    var lstatSync = require('fs').lstatSync,
        utimes = require('fs').utimes,

        LOGPATH = './.optimizeImagesLog.json',

        daysAgo = grunt.option('daysAgo') || 30, // Default 30 days.
        nowDate = Date.now(),
        maxDate = nowDate - (daysAgo * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
        minDate,

        originalModDates = [],
        optimizedFiles = [],

        isFirstRun = false;

    /**
     * If '...Log.json' exists the `optimizeImages` task has previously run. To
     * help circumvent reprocessing images the 'lastMaxMs' value is assigned
     * to 'minDate'. The first time the task is run the '...Log.json' doesn't yet
     * exist, therefore circumventing the reprocessing of images is not necessary.
     */
    try {
        minDate = grunt.file.readJSON(LOGPATH).dates.lastMaxMs;
    } catch (e) {
        isFirstRun = true;
    }

    /**
     * Check files modified date is <= 'maxDate' when the 'optimizeImages' task
     * is run for the first time. For subsequent runs check the file modified
     * date is within the 'minDate' and 'maxDate' range to avoid reprocessing.
     *
     * @param {String} filePath - The filepath for the file to check.
     * @return {Boolean} - True if modified date is in range, otherwise false.
     */
    function isModDateInRange(filePath) {
        var modDate = new Date(lstatSync(filePath).mtime),
            modDateMs = new Date(modDate).getTime(),

            inRange = isFirstRun
                    ? modDateMs <= maxDate
                    : modDateMs <= maxDate && modDateMs > minDate;

        // Temporarily cache filepath and original modified date so
        // it can be reinstated via the 'setOriginalDates' task.
        if (inRange) {
            originalModDates.push([filePath, modDate]);
            optimizedFiles.push({
                file: filePath,
                modDate: humanizeDate(modDate)
            });
        }

        return inRange;
    }

    /**
     * Converts epoch milliseconds date to human readable.
     *
     * @param {Number} ms - The date as milliseconds.
     * @return {String} - Human readable date. E.g. Fri, 17 Mar 2017 10:05:50 GMT
     */
    function humanizeDate(ms) {
        return new Date(ms).toUTCString();
    }

    grunt.initConfig({

        imagemin: {
            dateRange: {
                options: {
                    optimizationLevel: 5
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'images/', // <-- Change this as required.
                    src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
                    dest: 'images/', // Value must equal 'cwd' value.

                    rename: function(dest, src) {
                        return dest + src;
                    },

                    filter: function (filePath) {
                        return isModDateInRange(filePath);
                    }
                }]
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');

    /**
     * Write 'maxDate' value, (as milliseconds since epoch), to log file so the
     * 'minDate' range can be determined when the 'optimizeImages' task re-runs.
     * Also include human readable dates for when the task last run and 'maxDate'
     */
    grunt.registerTask('updateLastTimeLog', 'Writes maxDate value to log',
        function() {
            var log = {};
            log.dates = {
                lastRun: humanizeDate(nowDate),
                lastMax: humanizeDate(maxDate),
                lastMaxMs: maxDate
            };
            log.files = optimizedFiles;

            grunt.file.write(LOGPATH, JSON.stringify(log));
        }
    );

    /**
     * Sets the file modified date back to its original value. When an image is
     * optimized it gets a new modified date, so reinstating the original date
     * circumvents it from being reprocessed when 'optimizeImages' task is rerun.
     */
    grunt.registerTask('setOriginalDates', 'Sets modified date to original date',
        function() {
            originalModDates.forEach(function(item) {
                utimes(item[0], item[1], item[1]);
            });
        }
    );

    grunt.registerTask('optimizeImages', [
        'imagemin:dateRange',
        'updateLastTimeLog',
        'setOriginalDates'
    ]);

};
```

---

**Notes**

- The `Gruntfile.js` above is configured to use a custom Task for the [grunt-contrib-imagemin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-imagemin) plugin and includes a custom [Target](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets) named `dateRange`.
- The task initially `cwd` to the `images` folder. You'll need to change this value as necessary. It should point to the top-level folder containing the images that you intend to optimize, and should be relative to the location of the `Gruntfile.js`. The value for `dest` must equal this value to ensure the optimized images are written back to their original location/path.
- `src` utilizes the globbing pattern, `**/*.{png,jpg,gif}`, which builds an array of paths to all image files *(.png, .jpg, .gif)* found in the `images` folder including subfolders.
- The `rename` function ensures the optimized image files are written to the same location.
- The `filter` function filters the array of all image paths and returns only those with an `mtime` within the date range.

---

**.optimizeImagesLog.json**

Each time the `optimizeImages` task runs it writes an invisible `.json` log file on completion. As you can see from the example below it includes:

- `dates.lastRun` - The date when the `optimizeImages` task was last run.
- `dates.lastMax` - The date **x** no. of days ago. For example, to produce the log below I ran the task using `grunt optimizeImages --daysAgo=45` so the value for `lastMax` below is 45 days before the `lastRun` date.
- `dates.lastMaxMS` - The `lastMax` value as milliseconds since epoch.
- `files` - An array of files that were optimized the last time the task run.
- `file` - The path to the file.
- `modDate` - The files modified date.

```json
{
  "dates": {
    "lastRun": "Mon, 20 Mar 2017 14:51:40 GMT",
    "lastMax": "Fri, 03 Feb 2017 14:51:40 GMT",
    "lastMaxMs": 1486133500520
  },
  "files": [
    {
      "file": "images/a.png",
      "modDate": "Wed, 01 Feb 2017 12:00:00 GMT"
    },
    {
      "file": "images/b.png",
      "modDate": "Thu, 02 Feb 2017 12:00:00 GMT"
    },
    {
      "file": "images/c.jpg",
      "modDate": "Fri, 03 Feb 2017 12:00:00 GMT"
    }
  ]
}
```

`dates.lastMaxMS` has significant importance as it's the only property/value that the `Gruntfile.js` depends on (except when the task first runs). However, the other values may be useful for reporting purposes.

Important: The `.optimizeImagesLog.json` MUST NOT be deleted as the `dates.lastMaxMs` value is read the next time the task runs.  This value is utilized to circumvent images previously optimized from being reprocessed.

---

**Running the Grunt/cron Task**

You'll need to run/execute the following grunt command:

`$ grunt optimizeImages`

When executing the command above it will optimize any images with an `mtime` that is 30 days ago or less/older. The default value has been set to 30 days in the `Gruntfile.js`.

However, the `Gruntfile.js` has been developed to accept an optional `--daysAgo` argument. For example if your cron task is set to run every 90 days then you would run the following command:

`$ grunt optimizeImages --daysAgo=90`

In short, the value specified for the `--daysAgo` argument should match the no. of days your *cron* task is configured to run. It's important that whichever no. of days ago you choose that you continue to use the same again the next time the *cron* runs.

Grunt includes several built-in arguments/options found [here](http://gruntjs.com/using-the-cli). The pertinent ones for your scenario are probably [--gruntfile](http://gruntjs.com/using-the-cli#gruntfile) and [--base](http://gruntjs.com/using-the-cli#base-b).

---

**Additional info**

Image optimization is often a slow process, so I recommend that you experiment with the duration time for when the cron task is run (A more frequent duration, i.e. less than 90 days, may be better), and also try setting different image [optimization levels](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-imagemin#optimizationlevel-png) in the `Gruntfile.js` configuration.

Additionally this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735043/running-grunt-and-node-as-batch-files-through-cron) may be useful. It includes info on how to include the path to *node* and *grunt* executables in the shell script  when executing a `.sh` from *cron*.

Image files that are optimized typically get a new modified date, however, the files original modified date is reapplied before the task completes. So, you'll not see any date changes - only reductions in file size.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for such a detailed reply and answer. I will certainly look at this in the morning and play with this on a new testbed server I just set up. Will report back :)

Comment: My pleasure! However, having just read your OP again I'm pretty sure I misinterpreted the logic required. My answer optimizes any images with a ***newer*** date from a given no. of days ago. I guess what you really wanted was a way to  optimize any images with an ***older*** date from a given no. of days ago?

Comment: Hi Rob, yes indeed, I want to optimize images older than the given x no of days. Honestly had no chance to look at this yet as I've been running up and down to hospitals for the past 6 weeks with my Dad being very ill. But I hope to look as this on sunday. Apologies for the delay.